# Override PasswordSignInAsync AspNet Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to create a second Login form, but the column in database isn't "PasswordHash" will be other column, How I do to override the "PasswordSignInAsync" to accept password in other column?

Comment: You should do that in your EF model.

Comment: May you give me a example?

Comment: Create a normal EF model, but map the `PasswordHash` property to whatever your column is named.

Comment: you would need a custom implementation of [UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) or modified model mapping in the EF code

Comment: but I need of two access the pattern(with PasswordHash) and other with(PasswordMaster), so I will have two logins forms.

Comment: ok, in my EF is set the new column. but How I do to change the user to SignedIn = true. I tried `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);` but not work

Comment: My problem is that I use this code `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true); ` but it happness the mistake: `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value`

Comment: Not get yet! I tried but not get login with other column